# Creating points on multiple lines

Tags: arcgis-10.0

How would I create points along a line on multiple lines?

We are mapping our vineyards, and in some cases the rows are straight, and parallel. So for example, I've got 86 rows, and each row has 93 vines. How do I first create the 86 rows without having to copy parallel every time, and then how do I create the 93 vines along each one of those rows without needing to construct points every time?

I've been messing around, and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right you are looking for a function similar to AutoCAD's "Copy Multiple". I don't know about a similar tool in ArcGIS. So what I suggest here is just a work-around for your question.

I'd use the free [Station Points](http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/stationPoints.htm) function in the otherwise commercial ET GeoWizards.

For each line it allows you to create evenly distributed points along the line. You have to compute the length of each line first and divide it by e.g. 92 to get the distance between the stations, which is an input parameter to the tool. You may run the tool for all lines with precisely the same length at once, but you have to repeat the proecdure for each group of lines with their own length.

You still have to draw your rows beforehand, so it is really just a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m reading you correctly, this solution might work.  Use the ArcToolbox>DataManagementTools>Create Fishnet tool to create an initial 86 x93 grid.  This will be equivalent to your 86 rows, with the intersections of the lines being equivalent to the point locations.  You can then use the ArcToolbox>DataManagementTools>FeatureVertices to Points tool to create points at the intersections.  You can then remove the lines that you do not need.  Just an idea, may or may not do what you need.